# How to convert Date column format in case class of Scala?

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, case, date-format

I am using Scala spark.I have two similar CSV files with 10 columns.One difference is with the Date column format.
1st file Date format yyyy-MM-dd
2nd file Date format dd-MM-yyyy
Objective is to: create seperate schema rdd for each file and finally merge both the Rdds.

For the first case class, I have used Date.valueOf [java.sql.Date] in the case class mapping.No issues here..

Am finding issue with the 2nd file Date format..
I have used the same Date.valueOf mapping..but it's throwing error in the date format...

How can I map the date format in the second file as like the 1st format yyyy-MM-dd? Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java.util.Date:

```
val sDate1="31/12/1998"
val date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1)  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
```

Result:

```
sDate1: String = 31/12/1998
date1: java.util.Date = Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 1998
```

to change the output format as a common string format.

```
val date2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
date2.format(date1)
```

Result:

```
res1: String = 1998/12/31
```